# Java: Convert scientific notation to regular int

Tags: java

How do I convert scientific notation to regular int
For example: 1.23E2
I would like to convert it to 123

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the string "1.23E2" or a `float` that is equal to 1.23e2?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you have your value as a String, you could use

```
int val = new BigDecimal(stringValue).intValue();
```

Comment: I used something like:
String val = new BigDecimal(stringValue).toPlainString();
since I wanted the value back as String. Thanks for pointing me to BigDecimal

Comment: Fighting with some scientific-notation-formatted value from Excel (using POI) which happens to be a date in format "yyyyMMdd". This was really helpful!

Comment: Old post but it's worth noting that the method `new BigDecimal(stringValue).intValueExact()` will only return int value if it fits in the range and has no fractional part. Otherwise it will throw `ArithmeticException`. Might avoid unexpected truncation/rounding.

Comment: Not working for high range like, 5000000000

Answer (score 3):

You can just cast it to `int` as:

```
double d = 1.23E2; // or float d = 1.23E2f;
int i = (int)d; // i is now 123
```

Comment: I actually tried this before posting the question here on stackoverflow but for some reason I decided not to use it since I was afraid of losing information during this conversion to Double and then to Int. But I guess it is a valid way.

Comment: This is not valid.  You are correct in thinking that some information will be lost.  This is because doubles are 8 bytes while ints are 4 bytes.  Take this as an example and notice the large difference after casting.

  `double dlow = Double.parseDouble("-2299999999");
  int ilow = (int) dlow;
  System.out.println("dlow="+String.valueOf(dlow));
  System.out.println("(int)dlow="+String.valueOf(ilow));
  System.out.println("ilow-dlow="+String.valueOf(ilow-dlow));`

`dlow=-2.299999999E9
(int)dlow=-2147483648
ilow-dlow=1.52516351E8`

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you have it as a string.

Take a look at the [DecimalFormat](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html#numberpattern) class. Most people use it for formatting numbers as strings, but it actually has a parse method to go the other way around! You initialize it with your pattern (see the tutorial), and then invoke parse() on the input string.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [DecimalFormat.parse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-).

Sample code:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
Number num = df.parse("1.23E2", new ParsePosition(0));
int ans = num.intValue();
System.out.println(ans); // This prints 123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like this.

```
(int) Double.parseDouble("1.23E2")
```

Answer (score -2):

You can implement your own solution:

```
String string = notation.replace(".", "").split("E")[0]
```

Comment: If the string looks like `"1.23E4"` you'll get 123 instead of `12300`; or `"1.234E1"` will result in `1234` instead of `12`. The string needs to be parsed properly using existing facilities mentioned in other answers for the past 10 years..