# Converting large scientific number to long

Tags: java, long-integer, scientific-notation

I've spend a long time now, trying to convert the number 1.2846202978398e+19 in java, without any luck. Currently what I'm trying to do `(long)Double.parseDouble(hashes)`, however this gives 9223372036854775807, which is obviously incorrect. The actual number should look something like this 12855103593745000000.

Using `int val = new BigDecimal(stringValue).intValue();` returns `-134589568` as it's unable to hold the result. Switching the code to `long val = new BigDecimal(hashes).longValue();` gives me -5600541095311551616 which is also incorrect.

I'm assuming this is happening due to the size of a double compared to a long.

Any ideas?

Comment: bigdecimal?? biginteger??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Convert scientific notation to regular int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546147/java-convert-scientific-notation-to-regular-int)

Comment: Updated question to reflect your comments :)

Comment: `12_855_103_593_745_000_000 > 9_223_372_036_854_775_807 (Long.MAX_VALUE)`

Comment: @Jazerix the suggestion to use BigDecimal/BigInteger was not meant to mean that you should go from double to long _via_ BigDecimal/BigInteger! Just use BigInteger directly and forget about long: it's not long enough.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try to use `String.format` :

```
String result = String.format("%.0f", Double.parseDouble("1.2846202978398e+19"));
System.out.println(result);
```

**Output**

```
12846202978398000000
```

---

**Edit**

Why you don't work with `BigDecimal` to do the arithmetic operations, for example :

```
String str = "1.2846202978398e+19";
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(str).multiply(BigDecimal.TEN);
//                                 ^^^^^^^^------example of arithmetic operations


System.out.println(String.format("%.0f", d));
System.out.println(String.format("%.0f", Double.parseDouble(str)));
```

**Output**

```
128462029783980000000
12846202978398000000
```

Comment: That works! But this solution disallows me from doing any arithmetic operations ^^

Comment: @Jazerix why you don't work with `BigDecimal` and the result show it like i do?

Comment: BigInteger and BigDecimal can be passed directly to String.format; no need to use parseDouble.

Comment: thank you @KlitosKyriacou for your information i already edit it :)

Answer (score 4):

Your value exceeds the maximum size of `long`. You can not use `long` in this situation.
Try

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("1.2846202978398e+19");
```

After that, you can call

```
value.toBigInteger()
```

or

```
 value.toBigIntegerExact()
```

if needed.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1.2846202978398e+19").toBigInteger());
```