# Android app doesn't show SQL result as a number

Tags: java, sql

I've been developing an android app on Android Studio, and I've reached to the point where it's working, and I'm able to get data from my external SQL DB.
The problem is, when I press Get Data button on my app, I get a number with a decimal point, and it ends with E12. For example, 8.41095645265E12. Yet, the number I entered into my database, is 8410376016789.
The data type used for the specific column is int(255), PK, NN. I've tried switching it to varchar, and between PK and NN on my workbench, but it still remains. My guess is that it's not an SQL-related issue.

Here's my code for the activity

```
package com.example.manager.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SeventhActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ItemAdapter itemAdapter;
Context thisContext;
ListView myListView;
TextView progressTextView;
Map<String, Double> myprojectMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fourth);

    Resources res = getResources();
    myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    progressTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressTextView);
    thisContext = this;

    progressTextView.setText("");
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getDataButton);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GetData retrieveData = new GetData();
            retrieveData.execute("");
        }
    });
}

private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

    String msg = "";
    // JDBC Driver name and database URL
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    // Example 10.20.30.40:3306
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://" +
            DbStrings.DATABASE_URL + "/" +
            DbStrings.DATABASE_NAME;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressTextView.setText("Connecting to Database...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DbStrings.USERNAME, DbStrings.PASSWORD);

            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM mythisone.codes";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                String name = rs.getString("Toode");
                double price = rs.getDouble("Hind");

                myprojectMap.put(name, price);
            }

            msg = "Process complete.";

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException connError) {
            msg = "An exception was thrown for JDBC.";
            connError.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            msg = "A class not found exception was thrown.";
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try {
                if (stmt != null) {
                    stmt.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {

        progressTextView.setText(this.msg);

        if (myprojectMap.size() >0) {

            itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(thisContext, myprojectMap);
            myListView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
        }

    }
}

} //END of MainActivity
```

Is there anything I left unnoticed?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doubles are problematic, and imprecise:

```
           double price = rs.getDouble("Hind");
```

With decimals:

```
           BigDecimal price = rs.getBigDecimal("Hind");
```

Without:

```
           long price = rs.getLong("Hind");
```

(Limited though to 2^63, ca 8*10^18)

One has two problems with double:

- The representation (minor, and also for BigDecimal). However a BigDecimal has `toPlainString()` which does away with the scientific notation 3E4 -> 30000.
- It approximates a number using a sum of powers of 2. For decimals with an error, for large numbers with a gap (the next larger double being more than 1 larger).

Comment: Thanks for replying. Whenever I try to edit the long price = rs.getLong("Hind"); , it gives me an error below at myprojectMap.put(name, price); where it underlines price, and says that wrong 2nd argument type found.

Comment: That is as the map also maps to Double, do: `Map<String, Long> myprojectMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();`

Comment: When I change that, the app unfortunately stops upon hitting Get Data button.

Answer (score 1):

The number being returned is in [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

To look at converting to a regular int, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546147/java-convert-scientific-notation-to-regular-int?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
Edited this:

```
priceTextView.setText(prices.get(position).toString());
```

to this:

```
priceTextView.setText(String.format("%.0f", prices.get(position)));
```